# How can i do nested field queries in Elastic search using Lucene query syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Here is the simple usecase,

I have a system that sends the Lucene query to my elastic search. I have a mapping

```json
{
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "grocery_name":{
        "type": "text"
       },
      "items": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "stock": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "category": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the data looks like

```json
{
  "grocery_name": "Elastic Eats",
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "banana",
      "stock": "12",
      "category": "fruit"
    },
    {
      "name": "peach",
      "stock": "10",
      "category": "fruit"
    },
    {
      "name": "carrot",
      "stock": "9",
      "category": "vegetable"
    },
    {
      "name": "broccoli",
      "stock": "5",
      "category": "vegetable"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I query to get all items where the item name is **banana** and **stock > 10**, In KQL i can write something like `items:{ name:banana and stock > 10 }`

Answer (score 1):

The Lucene expression language doesn't support querying nested documents. That's why the KQL language fills that gap.

That's currently the only way to query nested documents via the Kibana search bar.